# Trying to RayTrace in LWJGL, detecting an object

Tags: java, 3d, lwjgl, raytracing, raycasting

I am trying to write Ray Tracing in the LWJGL to go from the mouse position to the end of the display. I have written the code to find the mouse positions and to create the Vector3's for the start and end position of the rays, but how do I 'fire' the ray and detect an object?

I have tried using Camera's for the positioning, but my friend is the one who wrote the main Display system and its pretty gargled up and hard to read. Instead I opted for just firing the ray from the mouse position inside of the Display to the back Z of the display.

```
    public class Picker {

    static Vector3f startRay;
    static Vector3f endRay;

    public Picker() {
        startRay = new Vector3f();
        endRay = new Vector3f();
    }

    private static Vector2f getMouseCoords() {
        float x = (2f* Mouse.getX()) / Display.getWidth() - 1;
        float y = (2f * Mouse.getY()) / Display.getHeight() - 1f;
        return new Vector2f(x, y);
    }

    public static String getRayStr() {
        float x = (2f* Mouse.getX()) / Display.getWidth() - 1;
        float y = (2f * Mouse.getY()) / Display.getHeight() - 1f;
        String str = "Mouse X: " + x + " Mouse Y: " + y;
        str += "\nStart X: " + startRay.x + " Start Y: " + startRay.y + " Start Z: " + startRay.z; 
        str += "\nEnd X: " + endRay.x + " End Y: " + endRay.y + " End Z: " + endRay.z; 
        return str;
    }

    public static void setStartRay() {
        Vector2f mousePos = getMouseCoords();
        Vector3f tempStartPos = new Vector3f();
        tempStartPos.x = mousePos.x;
        tempStartPos.y = mousePos.y;
        tempStartPos.z = 0;

        startRay = tempStartPos;
    }

    public static void setEndRay() {
        Vector2f mousePos = getMouseCoords();
        Vector3f tempEndPos = new Vector3f();
        tempEndPos.x = mousePos.x;
        tempEndPos.y = mousePos.y;
        tempEndPos.z = -1;

        endRay = tempEndPos;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to detect an object directly inbetween startRay and endRay. The object I want to detect is a 3d model inside of the Display area.

Returning the startRay and endRay Vector3 positions has already confirmed to work, just needing to know about how to:
1) Cast the ray
2) Detect an object between the two points

Thank you very much for your assistance.